# How woulld I add $OPTARGs from one arg to an array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, array, arguments

So I'm trying to add values from an optarg to an array. I've got:

```
arrays=()
while getopts a: args; do
  case $args in
    a) arrays+=$OPTARG;;
  esac
done
echo $arrays[@]
```

When I run the script, ./script -a foo bar, I get returned with

```
foo
```

Any idea how to add more values?

Comment: Have you tried `./script -a foo -a bar`?

Comment: `var+=val` is string appending, `ary+=(val)` is array appending.

Answer (score 1):

`$OPTARGS` holds the next **word**. If you want multiple values

- specify `-a value` multiple times as @scott suggests
- provide a multi-word string in quotes on the command line:

  ```
  ./script -a "foo bar baz"
  ```

  then, in the script

  ```
  array+=($OPTARG)   # OPTARG is **unquoted**
  ```

  Checking that it adds the words separately

  ```
  a=(one two three)
  value="four five six"
  a+=($value)
  echo ${#a[@]}        # prints 6
  ```